# How do I batch-convert files from an input list using ImageMagick 'convert'?

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I'd like to use ImageMagick's `convert` command to convert a batch files from GIF to PNG format.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.  I have a file `gif-list` containing the names of files in GIF format, one per line and with the `.gif` extension.  From the command line, I'd like to read in this file and apply `convert` to non-destructively produce a new PNG-format file with `.png` extension for each input.

How do I do this?  From searching, I've found answers to individual bits of the problem, but I can't put all the bits together on my own or find the exact question.

Comment: There's this kind of info [on their site](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read file; do
    convert "$file" "${file%.gif}.png"
done < gif-list
```